# How to add security headers to Apache Airflow Web UI

Tags: airflow

We are using Apache Airflow 2.3.3 version. When I connect to the instance, I don't see any security headers related to HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) or X-Content-Type-Options etc. included in the response.. For example see below:

```
curl -D - https://127.0.0.1:8080
HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
Server: gunicorn
Date: Wed, 24 Aug 2022 21:26:40 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 339
Location: /login/?next=https%3A%2F%127.0.0.1%3A8080%2Fhome
X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow
Set-Cookie: session=XXXXXXXXXXXXX; Expires=Wed, 24 Aug 2022 22:26:40 GMT; HttpOnly; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
```

I am looking for something like this in the response (in addition to above):

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block  <-- I don't need it
```

How can I enable/add these to Airflow Web UI?

I looked at [Gunicorn Documentation](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#secure-scheme-headers) but it doesn't seem like I can add these.. They are very specific to reverse proxy parameters.

I do see that this is possible from
[Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/security/) but I am not sure where to add in Airflow?

Do I add it after [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/www/app.py#L92)? But that's like modifying the code and not sustainable during upgrades.. I am guessing there are better ways to do this without altering the code.. Any thoughts please? Thank you.

Also, this is similar to [Previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69639796/how-to-set-security-headers-like-content-security-policy-hsts-and-x-xss-protec)

Comment: Hi, did you get the solution to this ?  I am also facing the same problem

Comment: I initially created another file under <airflow_python_virtual_instance>/airflow/www/extensions and added whatever security headers I needed and initialized to run "after_request" decorator and imported this file under <airflow_python_virtual_instance>/airflow/www/app.py and added to flask_app. Unfortunately I can't copy+paste code here as that is my work computer.  

I finally switched to nginx frontend and made airflow listen to localhost:8080

Comment: @Lerner2016 could you elaborate on the switching to nginx part? did you set it up as a proxy? how did you do it? many thanks!

Comment: @Zach Sorry, didn't see this till now. Basically set endpoint_url to http://localhost:8080 in airflow.cfg file and the reverse proxy the nginx to this one. This is more safer as people access nginx front-end (without port #) and can't directly access airflow gunicorn server, thereby limiting all issues. All the security headers will now be configured in the nginx. Hope this helps.